# can't pass a correct value in betwen PHP pages

Tags: php

if my question appears to be silly but I ran out of explanations.
I'm trying to set up a page with some news on it. I have the database with such attributes like News_id, news_header, news body etc.

I have 2 pages first page gives a list of the brief descriptions of the news with the button which allows user to read some more of a particular news on it. If clicked it passes a corresponding news_id value to the page 2 which fetches News_Id Value, queries corresponding values from database value  and outputs the content.

The problem is that no mater which button in the list of page 1 I click to see news, the page 2 always receives the news_id value of the news which is **first in the lin**e. here are the codes

**PAGE ONE (the list)**

```
<form name='NewsLineSelection' method='post' action='news.php'>
<?php
 $News_Query = "Select * from news order by Date_Posted Desc;";
 $GetNews = mysql_query( $News_Query, $IVE_Connection ) or die("ERROR: ".mysql_error());

while ( $News_Database = mysql_fetch_array( $GetNews ) ){                   
?>
<tr><td ><?php echo $News_Database[1]; ?></td>//header
<tr><td ><?php echo $News_Database[2]; ?></td>//news body
...etc

<tr><td class="maintext">
<input type='hidden' name='NewsToRead' value='<?php echo $News_Database[0]; ?>'>//News_ID is here
<input type='submit' name='AddNews' value='Read More...' >
</td></tr>
 }//end of the loop
```

**Page 2 (with info details)**

```
$News_id = addslashes($_POST['NewsToRead']);

$News_Query = "Select * from news where news_id = ".$News_id.";";
$GetNews = mysql_query( $News_Query, $Connection ) or die("ERROR: ".mysql_error());
$News_Database = mysql_fetch_row( $GetNews );

//Then output the query's content
```

It looks perfect on paper. But I really can't understand why if there are 10 news in the list of page 1 for instance, no matter which button I click the value of $News_id in PAGE 2 will be always the id of the first news in the list on the page 1.

May be I don't see something. it suppose to work ok, but it doesn't.

Thanks for any kind of help or suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ). Also, don't use tables for laying out web pages.

Comment: yes the if the value of the first news is 1 nomatter what I click page 2 always receives 1 and therefore outputs the wrong content

Comment: yes but there is the loop as you can see. raw suppose to have a new values. and the headers and body texts are actually different.

Answer (score 5):

That's because you're having multiple inputs with the same name. You're looking at the problem wrong.

You're fetching (getting) data, you should be using a GET request, and not a POST request.

My recommendation, that each News headline would be wrapped in a link like so:

```
<h1>
    <a href="news.php?id=<?php //Code to output the correct ID here ?>"><?php //Code to output the correct headline here ?>
    </a>
</h1>
```

### A few things extra

- Don't use tables for laying out your page! Tables are meant for table data. Use correct semantic elements: (`<h1>` for important headlines, `<h2>` for less important headlines, `<p>` for paragraphs, and so on).
- [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: do you mean I have to replace the <input> button with a link?

Comment: @meks: I mean, don't use forms for something that doesn't need to be a form. (Or a table for something that doesn't need to be a table for that matter)

Comment: Ive just tried to change the value of the "NewsToRead' from hidden to text and in the page 1 it outputs the correct Id for each news. What I can't understand why on earth the value of 'NewsToRead' in the page 2 is always 1???????????

Comment: @meks: Like I said, it's because you have a lot of hidden inputs with the same **name**. You shouldn't be having a form at all in this case. This isn't something user inputs and submits. You want a link from page to page, so use a link!

Comment: Dude and how can I get the value in the PAGE 2 if I just use the link?

Comment: @meks: Please learn about the difference between $_GET variables and $_POST variables.